# Why does the peformance of consistency check of the two models in Alloy have no difference?

Tags: alloy

I have two models as following. The first one describe the model.
The Node Gender and its related edges and constraints are removed in the second model. [image]

```
//Signatures for nodes
sig NPerson{}
abstract sig NGender{}
abstract sig NCivilStatus{}
lone sig Nmale, Nfemale extends NGender{}
lone sig Nmarried, Nsingle, Ndivorced, Nwidowed extends NCivilStatus{}

//Signatures for edges
sig Ehusband{src:one NPerson, trg:one NPerson}
sig Ewife{src:one NPerson, trg:one NPerson}
sig EpGender{src:one NPerson, trg:one NGender}
sig EpCivstat{src:one NPerson, trg:one NCivilStatus}

//facts
fact HasHusbandIsMarried{
    all h:Ehusband|let P0=h.src,P1=h.trg|
    (P0=h.src and P1=h.trg) implies (some civstat0:EpCivstat|let married=civstat0.trg|
    (civstat0.src=P0 and married in Nmarried)) 
}

fact inv_Ewife_Ehusband{
    all x:NPerson, y:NPerson| (some xy:Ehusband| xy.src=x and xy.trg=y) <=>  (some yx:Ewife| yx.src=y and yx.trg=x) 
}

fact multi_EpCivstat{
    //mulitplicity on pCivstat:Person->CivilStatusmin:1;max:1
    all n:(NPerson)| let count = #{e:(EpCivstat)| e.src = n}| count>=1 and count <=1}

fact MarriedWithoutHusband{
    all civstat0:EpCivstat|let P0=civstat0.src,married=civstat0.trg|
    married in Nmarried and not (some h:Ehusband|let P2=h.trg|
    h.src=P0) implies (some w:Ewife|let P1=w.trg|
    w.src=P0) 
}

fact HasWifeIsMarried{
    all wife0:Ewife|let P1=wife0.src,Person1=wife0.trg|
    (P1=wife0.src and Person1=wife0.trg) implies (some civstat0:EpCivstat|let married=civstat0.trg|
    (civstat0.src=P1 and married in Nmarried)) 
}

fact multi_EpGender{
    //mulitplicity on pGender:Person->Gendermin:1;max:1
    all n:(NPerson)| let count = #{e:(EpGender)| e.src = n}| count>=1 and count <=1}

fact mult1_Ehusband{
    //mulitplicity on husband:Person->Person[0,1]
    all n:(NPerson)| lone e:(Ehusband)|e.src=n
}

fact mult1_Ewife{
    //mulitplicity on wife:Person->Person[0,1]
    all n:(NPerson)| lone e:(Ewife)|e.src=n
}

fact xor_Ewife_Ehusband{
    //XOR constraint between wife:Person->Person and husband:Person->Person
    all n:(NPerson) | let e1 = (some e : Ewife | e.src = n), e2=(some e : Ehusband | e.src = n)|(e1 or e2) and not(e1 and e2)
}

fact MarriedWithoutWife{
    all s:EpCivstat|let p1=s.src,married=s.trg|
    married in Nmarried and not (some w:Ewife|let p3=w.trg|
    w.src=p1) implies (some h:Ehusband|let p2=h.trg|
    h.src=p1) 
}

fact surj_EpGender{
    //surjective on pGender:Person->Gender
    all n:(NGender)| some e:(EpGender)| e.trg = n
}

fact irr_Ehusband{
    //reflexive on husband:Person->Person
    no e:(Ehusband)| e.src = e.trg
}

fact AtLeastOneSingle{
    some civstat0:EpCivstat|let P0=civstat0.src,single=civstat0.trg|
    single in Nsingle
}

fact surj_EpCivstat{
    //surjective on pCivstat:Person->CivilStatus
    all n:(NCivilStatus)| some e:(EpCivstat)| e.trg = n
}

fact irr_Ewife{
    //reflexive on wife:Person->Person
    no e:(Ewife)| e.src = e.trg
}
```

Second model in Alloy

```
//Signatures for edges
sig Ehusband{src:one NPerson, trg:one NPerson}
sig Ewife{src:one NPerson, trg:one NPerson}
sig EpCivstat{src:one NPerson, trg:one NCivilStatus}

//facts
fact HasHusbandIsMarried{
    all h:Ehusband|let P0=h.src,P1=h.trg|
    (P0=h.src and P1=h.trg) implies (some civstat0:EpCivstat|let married=civstat0.trg|
    (civstat0.src=P0 and married in Nmarried)) 
}

fact inv_Ewife_Ehusband{
    all x:NPerson, y:NPerson| (some xy:Ehusband| xy.src=x and xy.trg=y) <=>  (some yx:Ewife| yx.src=y and yx.trg=x) 
}

fact multi_EpCivstat{
    //mulitplicity on pCivstat:Person->CivilStatusmin:1;max:1
    all n:(NPerson)| let count = #{e:(EpCivstat)| e.src = n}| count>=1 and count <=1}

fact MarriedWithoutHusband{
    all civstat0:EpCivstat|let P0=civstat0.src,married=civstat0.trg|
    married in Nmarried and not (some h:Ehusband|let P2=h.trg|
    h.src=P0) implies (some w:Ewife|let P1=w.trg|
    w.src=P0) 
}

fact HasWifeIsMarried{
    all wife0:Ewife|let P1=wife0.src,Person1=wife0.trg|
    (P1=wife0.src and Person1=wife0.trg) implies (some civstat0:EpCivstat|let married=civstat0.trg|
    (civstat0.src=P1 and married in Nmarried)) 
}

fact mult1_Ehusband{
    //mulitplicity on husband:Person->Person[0,1]
    all n:(NPerson)| lone e:(Ehusband)|e.src=n
}

fact mult1_Ewife{
    //mulitplicity on wife:Person->Person[0,1]
    all n:(NPerson)| lone e:(Ewife)|e.src=n
}

fact xor_Ewife_Ehusband{
    //XOR constraint between wife:Person->Person and husband:Person->Person
    all n:(NPerson) | let e1 = (some e : Ewife | e.src = n), e2=(some e : Ehusband | e.src = n)|(e1 or e2) and not(e1 and e2)
}

fact MarriedWithoutWife{
    all s:EpCivstat|let p1=s.src,married=s.trg|
    married in Nmarried and not (some w:Ewife|let p3=w.trg|
    w.src=p1) implies (some h:Ehusband|let p2=h.trg|
    h.src=p1) 
}

fact irr_Ehusband{
    //reflexive on husband:Person->Person
    no e:(Ehusband)| e.src = e.trg
}

fact AtLeastOneSingle{
    some civstat0:EpCivstat|let P0=civstat0.src,single=civstat0.trg|
    single in Nsingle
}

fact surj_EpCivstat{
    //surjective on pCivstat:Person->CivilStatus
    all n:(NCivilStatus)| some e:(EpCivstat)| e.trg = n
}

fact irr_Ewife{
    //reflexive on wife:Person->Person
    no e:(Ewife)| e.src = e.trg
}
```

I use run{} to check the consistency of the two models.
The two models have no instance.
I want to see the performance difference. So I use scope until 23.
But the result is not what I expected.

The model is inconsistent. So to find a valid instance of the model, or establish that there are no instances, I expect that the Analyzer will need to check every possible instance of the model. Intuitively, if we remove part of the structure, there should be fewer possible instances to be checked, which means less the checking should take less time.

But the performance for the second 
model is even worse than the one for the first model.
The following is the verification time in ms on the two models.

```
Scope m1    m2
3   158     11
4   95      59
5   109     105
6   245     157
7   364     256
8   871     402
9   1652    646
10  1861    1479
11  1406    2418
12  5421    4343
13  6886    2609
14  10425   6553
15  13081   5871
16  19731   19453
17  16491   22249
18  21984   18191
19  39671   45510
20  60001   49958
21  67709   67892
22  101256  97801
23  135082  168585
```

Can someone explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

At a very high level of abstraction, I think the answer to your puzzle lies in the discussion in section 2.2 of Jackson's *Software abstractions*:

> Of course, the analyzer doesn't construct and check each case individually; even if it used only one processor cycle per case, 10<sup>30</sup> cases [as in the example given earlier in sec. 2.2] would still take longer than the age of the universe.  By pruning the tree of possibilities, it can rule out large subspaces without examining them fully.

One might conjecture (but I haven't measured this!) that when the second model eliminates some constraints, it makes it harder to prune the search space.  (To measure this, I'd see if I could construct a third model that retains the extra signatures but not the constraints, and see how its times compare.)

Performance is almost always a complicated matter; you've taken the right first step by measuring instead of just speculating.

**[Postscript]** At a lower level of abstraction, I added a vacuous predicate and a `run` command to each of the two models included in the question, restored some missing signature declarations to the second, and compared the time it took to search for an instance in the default scope.  It's not clear to me that there is a consistent difference between the two models in terms of performance.  At a first glance, it appears that there is sometimes more variation between runs of the same model in the same scope than there is between model 1 and model 2.

```
Scope  Model 1...............  Model 2...............
       Trans.   Solve   Total  Trans.   Solve   Total

    3     132      32     164      17      11      28
           68      13      81      12      15      27 
           31      13      44      14       6      20
           23      12      35      10      47      57 
           13      16      29       9      15      24

    5      59      86     145      38     180     218
           37      88     125      54     103     157
           45      95     140      51     106     157
           31      89     120      24      89     113
           58      93     151      24      91     115

   10     640    6997    7637     140   13746   13886
          169    7237    7406     214   13717   13931
          189    6704    6893     188   15107   15295

   15     592   82872   83464     472   15522   15994
          543   78690   79233     574   16396   16970

   20    2701  840961  843662    1179 1082708 1083887
```

And looking again at the timings you report, I don't see any indication of the state of affairs you describe:

> But the performance for the second model is even worse than the one for the first model.

On the contrary, in 16 of the 21 scopes for which you report times, model 2 is faster, not slower.  And the difference is not particularly striking, either way:  the time you report for the two models is within ten or fifteen percent for the majority of scopes, and in the same order of magnitude for almost all scopes.  (So if you now tell me the columns were reversed for some or all rows, my answer will still be "tell me why you think this indicates a puzzling difference in performance".)

Comment: The second model delete not only constraints, but also part of the structure: two signatures.

Comment: Yes, it does. (Actually, more like eight signatures, judging by a diff between the two files you show above, but it appears that some of them were deleted by accident in the version you pasted here.) But it seems likely to be an empirical question whether the deletion of two signatures would have more effect on speed than the deletion of constraints. You say the second model is slower; if so, you know which change made more of a difference.  But the data you report tell the opposite story.

Comment: But theorectically, if we consider the analysis in Alloy as checking the tree of possibilities. The tree of possibilities for M2 is contained by the tree for M1, for every scope. The structure M1-M2 and its related constraints does not affect the the tree of possibilites for M2. Think about it. Since every test case of M2 is not instance of M2, it will never become an instance of M1 whenever adding elements typed by Gender or gGender (M1-M2).

Comment: It means, the test cases exmained for consistence of M2 are less than the test cases examined for consistence of M1. Therefore, the performance for M2 should always be better than M1, especially as long the scope grows. However, your report also shows the result oppsite to expectation.

Comment: Two points.  (1) You seem to be assuming that when the space of possible instances is larger, the Analyzer will have to examine more cases to exhaust the space.  But the number of cases the Analyzer will examine depends not only on the size of the space of possibilities, but also on the number of possibilities that the Analyzer can rule out by pruning the tree, which will depend on a lot of things other than size of tree.  And (2) you seem to believe there is a significant and consistent difference in performance here; why?  The numbers don't seem to show one.

Comment: I agree with your following statement.
"the number of cases the Analyzer will examine depends not only on the size of the space of possibilities, but also on the number of possibilities that the Analyzer can rule out by pruning the tree, which will depend on a lot of things other than size of tree"
To show that I understand your statement correctly, I give a demo. 
In the example, a person must have a gender. So when the Analyzer examines testcases, the test cases in which a person has no gender or has more than one gender will NOT be examined.
Am I correct?